# Rails passing in params to association on create method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am currently using a `belongs_to` relationship in my Rails application to link a map and a group an object that way I can assign those maps to the user based on the group they are in.

I have this `mapgroup` model.

```
class Mapgroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :map, optional: true
  belongs_to :group, optional: true
end
```

I am getting the map from a dropdown menu in the form but I don't want a dropdown for the group because the use is already in that group.

I opted to assign the `group_id` in the url to the mapgroup in the create method.

```
def create
  @mapgroup = Mapgroup.create(mapgroup_params)
  @mapgroup.group_id = params[:group_id] <-- right here

  respond_to do |format|
    if @mapgroup.save
      format.html { redirect_to groups_path, notice: 'Mapgroup crated' }
    else
      format.html { render :new, notice: 'That shit failed' }
    end
  end
end
```

Is this a good practice? I have done this in previous apps but it seems a bit...smelly. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: It's fine to assign attributes based onn the params. The one thing I would change about this would be to use `.new` instead of `create`. Since you call `save` later, if you use create you are saving twice which is unencessary. Also, I realize it's just a joke, but instead of returning some generic error message, you should include the validation errors from the model (`@mapgroup.errors.full_messages`)

Comment: If `params[:group_id]` comes from a URL param, i.e., `/groups/:group_id/maps`, I think it is _important_ that you write it this way (as a way to prevent POSTing to a group that does not match the URL)

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here:

- need to find parent model first, and then build association (as group_id could be wrong)
- `create` would try to save record, so you're trying to save twice. Use build/new instead.

```
    def create
      @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
      @mapgroup = @group.mapgroups.build(mapgroup_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @mapgroup.save
          format.html { redirect_to groups_path, notice: 'Mapgroup crated' }
        else
          format.html { render :new, notice: 'That shit failed' }
        end
      end
    end
```